# Filter function for an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, filtering

I need to implement function that filters array of objects. Filters array consists of objects with property names and values to be filtered for given property in users.

Example:

```
var filters = [
  {
    column: 'username',
    value: 'test user'
  },
  {
    column: 'name',
    value: 'test name'
  }
]

var users = [
    {
      name: 'test name user',
      username: 'some test user'
    },
    {
      name: 'another name',
      username: 'another username'
    }
]

// filter logic

console.log(users); // [{'name': 'test name user', 'username': 'some test user'}]
```

Comment: Mind showing us your attempt?

Comment: Have you used the array filter method?

Comment: You can use the native `filter` function available on `Array`: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter . Or you can use the `lodash` library which contains a `filter` function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#filter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate the list of user and [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) them by iterating with [Array#some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (Or - if at least one matches) or [Array#every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) (And - all must match).

```js
var filters = [{"column":"username","value":"test user"},{"column":"name","value":"test name"}];

var users = [{"name":"test name user","username":"test user"},{"name":"another name","username":"another username"}];

var result = users.filter(function(user) {
  return filters.some(function(filter) { // use some for Or, and every for And
    return user[filter.column] === filter.value;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Functions#ArrowFunctions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and сhange the original array like:

```js
var filters = [{"column":"username","value":"test user"},{"column":"name","value":"test name"}];

var users = [{"name":"test name user","username":"test user"},{"name":"another name","username":"another username"}];

users = users.filter((user) => {
  return filters.some((filter) => {
    return user[filter.column] === filter.value;
  });
});

console.log(users);
```